# Load many text files in a loop in arrays with different names with numpys loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy

I want to load multiple text files numbered consecutively with loadtxt. In the files are just columns with numbers. I already found the below shown in another question, but I'm not able to use the data. I would need to have the read in data arrays indexed like data1, data2, ... Thanks in advance!

```
for i in range(50):
    data = np.loadtxt('{0}.txt'.format(i+1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options: dict and list:

```
data_dict = {} # empty dict
data_list = [] # empty list

for i in range(50):
    data_list.append(np.loadtxt('{0}.txt'.format(i+1)))
    #or
    data_dict[i] = np.loadtxt('{0}.txt'.format(i+1))
```

later you can access your data by index:

```
data_dict[9] # access data10
#or
data_list[9]
```